# create new site collection with REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, flow

I am looking for a no-code solution to provision sites using the "Send HTTP Request to Sharepoint" action in Flow. Can somebody please point me to the correct Sharepoint API (so no Graph) that lets me create a new modern site collection without group?

I tried `/_api/GroupSiteManager/CreateGroupEx` and `/_api/GroupSiteManager/CreateGroup` but both create a group.
Also tried to [Create Communication site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/communication-site-creation-rest) but couldn't make it work, even with the sample on the page:

> The property '__metadata' does not exist on type
>   'SP.Publishing.CommunicationSiteCreationRequest'. Make sure to only
>   use property names that are defined by the type.

Any idea welcome, the goal is a modern site, no group, no powershell.

Comment: you want to create modern team site or communication site ?

Comment: As far as I've read, a communication site is basically a group-less modern team site, so at this point, doesn't matter. I want to control authorization with sharepoint groups per document library on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a modern communication site, you can use the below endpoint:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/SPSiteManager/Create
```

In the body, you need to send data as:

```
"request":
{
     "__metadata": { "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.SPSiteCreationRequest" },
     Title: "Test Comm site",
     Lcid: 1033,
     Description: "",
     Classification: "",
     ShareByEmailEnabled: false,
     SiteDesignId: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
     Url: "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite",
     WebTemplate: "SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0",
     WebTemplateExtensionId: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",     
}
```

Also, you need to set the headers as:

```
headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8",
          },
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to correct the json, but it works :) Is there any official documentation for this? I found references on github, but no real docs.

Comment: strange, will update the official docs for this then :) , at the moment just take my word for it !!